# Nullpointer exception while loading image from url

Tags: android, url, image-loading

I am developing an application with rest web service. By getting the json response from server, am parsing it and populating it in a custom list view using adapter. In that json response there are url's to download image to display in list items.  Every thing has been done and working fine, except loading image from url there is Nullpointer exception.
I have done debugging also, logcat shows as follows

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2269)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:602)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:415)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Force finishing activity com.shopping/.views.JsonListView
```

Can some one help me to find the reason why getting this exception.

Edit:

```
     int loader = R.drawable.fb_icon;
 // ImageLoader class instance
 ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(_Context);


 imgLoader.DisplayImage(imageUrl, loader, holder.productImage);
     public void DisplayImage(String url, int loader, ImageView imageView)
     {  
        stub_id = loader;
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
           imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(loader);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Some source code would be helpfull...

Comment: @Androholic Please post some code so we can help you more and are you using lazy loading for download and display image in listview.

Comment: yes, am using lazy loading. and please check the edit

Comment: @Dipak Yes, tested url and its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write below line into your adapter's getview() method.

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(url[position], imageview1);
```

and see below lazy loading link for more information and if you have any query regarding that then tell me.

[Lazy Loading Listview](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

Comment: am passing arraylist to adapter class that contains 2 strings (1 for text, 2nd for url). Converting that into String array in adapter constructor. and using those strings. how can i use that string like url[position]?

Comment: @Androholic Pass this string instead of url[position] and check.